# Unable to use Docker, even though the demon is active

Tags: docker

OS: Ubuntu LTS 22.4 | LTS 20.04
I had the same problem on ubuntu LTS 22.4 soo I downgraded to 20.04. I tried following all StackOverflow threads none of the solutions seems to work for me. I am not behind any proxy.

```
docker run hello-world
Unable to find image 'hello-world:latest' locally
docker: Error response from daemon: Get "https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/": proxyconnect tcp: dial tcp: lookup http: Temporary failure in name resolution.
```

Docker servic seems to be working just okay:

[image]

Similar error on trying to login:
[image]

If any additional detail is required let me know in the comments, ill edit!

Status logs:

```
Aug 15 11:15:19 asus systemd[1]: Started Docker Application Container Engine.
Aug 15 11:15:19 asus dockerd[9448]: time="2022-08-15T11:15:19.531101032+05:30" level=info msg="API listen on /run/docker.sock"
Aug 15 11:15:57 asus dockerd[9448]: time="2022-08-15T11:15:57.920565157+05:30" level=warning msg="Error getting v2 registry: Get \"https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/\": proxyconnect tcp: dial tcp: lookup http: no such host"
Aug 15 11:15:57 asus dockerd[9448]: time="2022-08-15T11:15:57.920602673+05:30" level=info msg="Attempting next endpoint for pull after error: Get \"https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/\": proxyconnect tcp: dial tcp: lookup http: no such host"
Aug 15 11:15:57 asus dockerd[9448]: time="2022-08-15T11:15:57.922360289+05:30" level=error msg="Handler for POST /v1.41/images/create returned error: Get \"https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/\": proxyconnect tcp: dial tcp: lookup http: no such host"
Aug 15 11:18:45 asus dockerd[9448]: time="2022-08-15T11:18:45.641224726+05:30" level=warning msg="Error getting v2 registry: Get \"https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/\": proxyconnect tcp: dial tcp: lookup http: no such host"
Aug 15 11:18:45 asus dockerd[9448]: time="2022-08-15T11:18:45.641275059+05:30" level=info msg="Attempting next endpoint for pull after error: Get \"https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/\": proxyconnect tcp: dial tcp: lookup http: no such host"
Aug 15 11:18:45 asus dockerd[9448]: time="2022-08-15T11:18:45.643035998+05:30" level=error msg="Handler for POST /v1.41/images/create returned error: Get \"https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/\": proxyconnect tcp: dial tcp: lookup http: no such host"
Aug 15 11:24:07 asus dockerd[9448]: time="2022-08-15T11:24:07.919119361+05:30" level=info msg="Error logging in to endpoint, trying next endpoint" error="Get \"https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/\": proxyconnect tcp: dial tcp: lookup http: no such host"
Aug 15 11:24:07 asus dockerd[9448]: time="2022-08-15T11:24:07.919328823+05:30" level=error msg="Handler for POST /v1.41/auth returned error: Get \"https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/\": proxyconnect tcp: dial tcp: lookup http: no such host"
lines 1-23
```

journalctl logs:

```
sudo journalctl -fu docker.service
[sudo] password for rhythm: 
-- Logs begin at Mon 2022-08-15 02:04:27 IST. --
Aug 15 13:18:20 asus dockerd[12520]: time="2022-08-15T13:18:20.454180157+05:30" level=info msg="Loading containers: done."
Aug 15 13:18:20 asus dockerd[12520]: time="2022-08-15T13:18:20.463895293+05:30" level=info msg="Docker daemon" commit=a89b842 graphdriver(s)=overlay2 version=20.10.17
Aug 15 13:18:20 asus dockerd[12520]: time="2022-08-15T13:18:20.463955619+05:30" level=info msg="Daemon has completed initialization"
Aug 15 13:18:20 asus systemd[1]: Started Docker Application Container Engine.
Aug 15 13:18:20 asus dockerd[12520]: time="2022-08-15T13:18:20.481004111+05:30" level=info msg="API listen on /run/docker.sock"
Aug 15 13:19:19 asus dockerd[12520]: time="2022-08-15T13:19:19.377705065+05:30" level=warning msg="Error getting v2 registry: Get \"https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/\": net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)"
Aug 15 13:19:19 asus dockerd[12520]: time="2022-08-15T13:19:19.377835945+05:30" level=info msg="Attempting next endpoint for pull after error: Get \"https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/\": net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)"
Aug 15 13:19:19 asus dockerd[12520]: time="2022-08-15T13:19:19.385691924+05:30" level=error msg="Handler for POST /v1.41/images/create returned error: Get \"https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/\": net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)"
Aug 15 13:30:26 asus dockerd[12520]: time="2022-08-15T13:30:26.166694545+05:30" level=info msg="Error logging in to endpoint, trying next endpoint" error="Get \"https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/\": net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)"
Aug 15 13:30:26 asus dockerd[12520]: time="2022-08-15T13:30:26.166963331+05:30" level=error msg="Handler for POST /v1.41/auth returned error: Get \"https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/\": net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)"
```

Comment: What is the result of `docker images | cut -d " " -f1 | grep hello-world`?

Comment: Got no results.

Comment: Then I guess you did not built your image yet, in order to run the command `docker run hello-world` you should have an existing docker image named `hello-world` for spawning a docker container.

Comment: It should definitely pull it from the docker hub.

Comment: $ docker login
$ Username: rhythmshandlya
$ Password: 
$ Error response from daemon: Get "https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/": proxyconnect tcp: dial tcp: lookup http: no such host

Comment: It seems some issue with you dns/connection. Can you ping hub.docker.com and ping google.com? And the dns is working? nslookup hub.docker.com nslookup google.com

Comment: ping hub.docker.com
PING prodextdefault-bh8fpp9uymz-123862781978072e.elb.us-east-1.amazonaws.com (34.224.198.167) 56(84) bytes of dat

Comment: ping google.com
PING google.com (142.250.193.206) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from del11s17-in-f14.1e100.net (142.250.193.206): icmp_seq=1 ttl=118 time=4.02 ms
64 bytes from del11s17-in-f14.1e100.net (142.250.193.206): icmp_seq=2 ttl=118 time=110 ms

Comment: I have added proper logs, you guys can check

Comment: Also posted on https://forums.docker.com/t/not-able-to-use-docker-even-though-the-demon-status-is-active/127799

Comment: yes, that's me.